# Choosing the right lenses for optical fiber

Tags: optics, lenses, fiber-optics

I need to measure optical emission of lanthanides when excited with X-ray, so I have to problems, difficult to align (X-ray radiation) and poor signal.
In this case I need to choose some lenses to capture as much light as possible, and bring them to the spectrometer.
I am more on the materials size, so I need some hints with the optics.
Does anyone ordered lenses to couple to the fiber at Thorlabs?
Any recommendation?
Best regards.

Comment: Just curious, if you add some lens to collect the beam, would it not change the intensity profile of the original spectrum since the lens itself also has an absorption spectrum?

Comment: @AndyChen Well, for visible lanthanide emission, e.g., around 616 nm for trivalent europium emission, the effect is minor. The fibers also have transmittances that vary with wavelength. I have three different 2 m long, multimode, silica step index Thorlabs optical fibers and their transmittances in the visible are not problematic. I just use simple collimating lenses to get light into the fibers, as shown [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49116/45954).

Comment: Thank you for your sharing! I used to work in the lab where laser light around 780 nm was used to cool down Rb atoms. Simple lenses were also used for collimating light into optical fiber. I just wonder whether there will be any particular difference because of the distinctions in  intention.

Comment: Thank you for your sharing! I used to work in the lab where laser light around 780 nm was used to cool down Rb atoms. Simple lenses were also used for collimating light into optical fiber. I just wonder whether there will be any particular difference because of the distinctions in  intention.

Comment: Maybe just as a hint: I had some issues with short fibers, they were extremely sensitive and the spectrum showed weird features. They adviced me to order longer fibers, as a rule of thumb 2 m, and loop if possible, for better mixing. The strange features dissapeared. But that was for Visible as well, guess you will have much more trouble with attenuation...

Comment: Hi all, thanks for all the comments, I found the problem is not so easy to solve. I will keep posting the setup I got.
Thanks!